# How to send (raw) mouse data to an application

Tags: c#

I want to replace user input (keyboard and mouse) to a game (Quake 2) by an external program for AI purposes. I am able to access the game from an external application, I am able to send keyboard data and mouse keys using [Input Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117657/InputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate), but the mouse movement data captured and generated in screen coordinates is not usable.
I think I need to (generate and) send raw data to the application. There are several articles about receiving raw mouse data such as [Raw input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496703/interpretation-of-raw-mouse-input), but I need to send it. How would I do that?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18379218/1997232) doesn't work?

Comment: @Sinatr: Good suggestion. Comes closer to anything I could find. Will check and revert.

Comment: @Sinatr: With that I am indeed able to get mouse movement into the game. Found more examples here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339565/send-mouse-keyboard-events).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate mouse move](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378142/simulate-mouse-move)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was answered with the comments by Sinatr. This is to be able to mark the question as answered.

Comment: This question was not answer then by Sinatr, but rather he posted a duplicate for you to follow. Hence, i think this question should be closed.

Comment: @austin, I do find the referenced question quite different, for instance I am targeting an external process, but the answer provided applied to my particular case also.